# How to control the drawing order of overlapping elements android activity?

Tags: android, user-interface, drawing, view

I think I have tried and researched enough, if not everything, yet I just can't get the two icons on the right get displayed in android emulator.
The strange thing is, that they are perfectly visible in design window.
Moreover, with similar/same GUI design, other activities display all my elements just fine.

I already know well, that how views overlap on screen depends on order of elements as I place them in the 'Component Tree' of Android Studio IDE.

Correctly looking design in Android Studio:

[image]

Missing icons on the right in emulator:

[image]

Moreover, the app in missing the title, which could be caused by an inappropriate parent activity class (its `Activity` which I changed from `AppCompatActivity` as I spent quite some time with the AS Designing tool).

1. **How else can I control the order of elements** when they overlap?
2. Or **what weird Android concept am I still missing**?
3. Or what has changed since all worked fine for me?

Below is the code XML for app design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile.ActivityTeacherHwkCheckByTask">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Problems"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:elevation="24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_problems" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Talar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:elevation="24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_talar" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ListOfTaskRows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:allowUndo="false"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="Úloha"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think if you just remove the `magrinTop = 57` from both `ImageViews` you can get what you want.

Comment: Anyone idea how to force my views to render on the top (i.e. visible) layer ?
Can't believe it can be so hard. And can't believe Android GUI design can be such a horrible mess either :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the fact that the `RelativeLayout` children are drawn in front of each other if they overlap. In your case you have a `TableRow` whose width is `match_parent` - it fills the parent's width but as it's added after the image views it's drawn in front of them.

You could constrain the table's width so that it leaves room for the images by setting it's [`layout_alignEnd`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignEnd) attribute to the id of your left-most image, so that the table would end where the image begins.

Comment: Hi @Stan0, Thanx so much for your tip. I have tried before to place those 2 icons below table row (as last views) to make sure they render on top. Stunningly this never worked for me, while elsewhere it does.. What am I doin' wrong ? What sort of Android "incantation" it expects me to spell ? :)
Setting the layout_alignEnd to shorter value not only does not display my icons, but it shortens the list of rows I programmatically add. Which I can't afford, you see.

Comment: @Peter why don't you try the Android Studio's Layout Inspector and see if you could find where the icons actually are? This might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanx @stan0 for your time, pal. I am pretty sure my icons are placed on right position - as you can see. But I will jot down your tips !
+1 for a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, believe it or not the reason for missing icons was, that I decided to derive my app from plain Activity and not AppCompatActivity as I had it before.

So I have **restored my activity to  `extends AppCompatActivity` again** and lo and behold.. It works.

This of course also enabled the Activity title again.

[image]

As **its a pure nonsence** (another one) and my **time wasted counts already in days** (not only this issue, but many other crappy designs and apparent bugs in ADT), I've just decided to abbandon native Android development in the near future and switch back to Xamarin/C# instead. (I've started my Android development from C# Xamarin 4 years ago and only left because of insufficient HW access support at that time).
Howhg !

Comment: Some good reading for others getting equally furious about ADT like me:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2hlw20/am_i_retarded_or_android_development_is_a_mess/
I like the top title "Am I retarded or Android Development is a mess ?"
Go, add your complain :D

Answer (score 0):

For user of "Material Design":

Another simple workaround is using ["elevation" property of any GUI element](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).
By increasing this value, one can force to draw this element on foreground over those with lower elevation.
As a bonus (or drawback), you get shading around your elevated GUI element according to how much you have elevated.

I wonder how much this feature prolongs rendering time
Another question is min supported API version. (Did not find it right away..)